# with ajax post and show recived data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I write this code, but it doesn't work. I want to show an array in php using ajax.
It's an html select that chooses every option of this select list value of the option take in the variable and sends it to ajax. Ajax should then post data to php then php select the received data from database and show all of them.
But I can't show this data in ajax. :(

```
$(function(){
    $("#topic").change(function(){
        var str = "";
        $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
            str += $( this ).text() + " ";
            options(str);
        });
    });
});

function options(option){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "/Register/checkSelect", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
        data: {
            option:option
        }).done(function(){
            $("#content").html(data);
            alert("ok");
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: you forgot to post your php code .

Comment: sorry this is PHP cod                                                                                public function checkSelect(){

        $getTopic= $_POST["topic"];

        $db=new db();
        $result= $db->query("SELECT * FROM topic WHERE topic='$getTopic'");

        foreach ($result as $topic) {
            echo $topic['keyword'];
         }


    }

Comment: You have no `data` argument in `done` callback. Also `html()` will replace all. Please use browser console/dev tools  to check for errors

Comment: i insert data but dont work

Comment: can you write a sample like this for me

Comment: You are missing an `}` to close the `data` value in your `ajax` call. You also have one `});` too many at the end of your `options` function.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your ajax request.
Here the right code:

```
function options(option){
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                url: "/Register/checkSelect", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
                data: {
                    option:option
                }
    }).done(function(data){
                 $("#content").html(data);
                 alert("ok");
   });
}
```

Comment: 1-> i send this data to php  2-> php select data from db 3 -> but i cant show this data.

Comment: Do you get alert OK?
If yes, can you print the data object:  console.log(data)?